# Using distance from two points to a line, how to find line slope?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have two point's coordinates and a distance to a line from each point (the distance is signed and measured on a normal perpendicular to the line). How can I find the line's slope?

Comment: Note that there are 3 different slopes among the 4 lines satisfying these conditions.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that the distance is signed (That means that I know which side of the line the distance is measured from).

Comment: I'd encourage you to re-ask this question at https://math.stackexchange.com/.  In truth this question should not have been closed, but rather migrated there.